# SQL Query of 2 tables finding missing value in table 2

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables in SQL.

-Table 1-

- Name
- ID

-Table 2-

- ID
- Program

Table 1 only holds a single record for each company.  In table 2, there can be multiple entries for a record in table 1.  So I could join the two tables together on ID = ID and get anywhere from 0 to 7 results.  I need to query the 2 tables where I am looking for any company from table 1 who is not in a specific program but they can be in other programs.  I know this is easy to do but I just can't get it to work for me.

Comment: Can you please use less abstract names and share some sample data & desired result for your tables?  I can't follow what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think the specific program in his input.\

Comment: After join do a where condition. Where table2.program not equal to program,ID

Comment: Abstract makes this easy.  Just looking to do a query where I get ID and Name from Table 1 but only show those who don't have a program entry for ProgramX in Table 2.

Comment: @Jayson you are correct that making something abstract can make it easy but dummying it down to Table1 and Table2 can make it hard for people to think of the business cases especially when your narration says table1 are companies and table2 are programs and then mix between that terminology and table names.  It is easier for most to conceptualize I have a table called companies with Name & ID and a table called Programs with CompanyId and Program.  Besides you don't name your tables in your databases Table1 and Table2 do you?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @Matt Understood and my tables are not named Tabel1 and Table2.  They are uniquely named and full of information.  I was just trying to show the basic comparison between the two tables and the information that I needed only for this query type.  One of the answers below took care of what I was needing.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
    AND t2.program = 'asdf'
WHERE
    t2.id IS NULL
```

Just use an OUTER JOIN place the program requirement on the join condition and then say where a record for the Table2 doesn't exist.

Trying to make this a little less ambiguous and adapting to your specific companies and programs:

```
SELECT *
FROm
    Companies c
    LEFT JOIN Programs p
    ON c.Id = p.CompanyId
    AND p.Program = 'some title'
WHERE
    p.Program IS NULL
```

And the NOT exists method:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Companies c
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
             FROM Programs p
             WHERE
                p.CompanyId = c.Id
                AND p.Program = 'some title')
```

I don't show the NOT IN method because I don't recommend it typically.

Comment: This one worked for what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jayson glad this worked out for you and happy to help, please consider accepting my answer or another if a different one helped so that others know your issue has been taken care of and reputation points are assigned.  Thanks! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.Name
  FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN 
       Table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.program IS NULL;
```

Comment: t2 doesn't have a name field it does have program.  but this would get you Programs Enrollments that have a company id NOT matching the company table which is the opposite of what is being asked.

Comment: now it will get companies that are not enrolled in ANY programs, by the time you get to your next edit you will likely just have my answer

Answer (score 0):

You want to get companies where they aren't in a program that you specify in the query? This is what I came up with:

```
select  t1.*
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
where coalesce(t2.Program, '') <> 'Name of Program'
```

or

```
where coalesce(t2.Program, '') not in (<comma-delimited list of programs>)
```